# Is there any case in which 見せてください and 見させてください are interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice

## Case A

When a police prompts me to show my id card, he might say:

> 在留カードを見せてください！

I am not sure whether it is natural if he says:

> 在留カードを見させてください！

## Case B

A boy enters an emergency room where his brother's wound is being sutured by a doctor. In order to avoid mental disturbance, his father covers the boy's eyes but he insists on seeing and says:

> 見させてください！

I am sure it is impossible to use

> 見せてください！

in this case.

## Question

Is there any case in which 見せてください and 見させてください are interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Case B can be interchangeble.

> 見させてください！

Let me see! (You are asking the dad for you to see him)

> 見せてください！

Please show me! (You are asking the dad not to hide him)

"在留カードを見させてください." is a bit odd for me if a policeman stops you to check it. Since normally he is an authority, they should use "在留カードを見せてください" when they stop you. I think  "在留カードをもう一度見させてください" is fine for making sure the number or somethiing.